# How to overlay texture over another, without clipping the base texture?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I have written this simple shader to overlay texture over another (base) texture -

```
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

 void main()
 {
     mediump vec4 base = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
     mediump vec4 overlay = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

     mediump float ra = (overlay.a) * overlay.r + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.r;
     mediump float ga = (overlay.a) * overlay.g + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.g;
     mediump float ba = (overlay.a) * overlay.b + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.b;

     gl_FragColor = vec4(ra, ga, ba, 1.0);
 }
```

**Issue** - This works except for one issue. If the overlay image is smaller than the base image, the outside region of overlay image gives alpha value of 1.0, i.e `overlay.a == 1.0`. Due to this the base image is clipped by overlay image. The region outside overlay appears as black.

I am new to opengl, and was expecting that outside its bounds, the texture's alpha should appear as 0.0? How can I fix my shader code to achieve desired behaviour? Or do I need to modify my graphics pipeline?

**EDIT** Vertex shader below-

```
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate2;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pos;
    textureCoordinate = uv;
    textureCoordinate2 = inputTextureCoordinate2.xy;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your vertex shader code too?

Comment: @Swifter: added vertex shader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my code. I had

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

in my code. Changing it to -

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

fixed the issue.

Also as mentioned by @Reto, I have changed my fragment shader to use vector operations for optimisation.

```
 void main()
 {
     mediump vec4 overlay = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

     mediump vec3 col = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).xyz;
     col = mix(col, overlay.xyz, overlay.a);

     gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting that outside its bounds, the texture's alpha should appear as 0.0

How are you sampling the texture outside of its bounds?  When sampling a texture, the uv coordinates should range from 0 to 1.  If the coordinates are outside of this range, then one of two things will happen:

- If `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is set, then the cooridnate will be clamped to the (0, 1) range, and you'll sample an edge pixel
- If `GL_REPEAT` is set, then the fractional part of the coordinate will be taken, and you'll sample somewhere in the middle of the texture

See [the docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/) on glTexParameter for more details.

If your use case is simply overlaying images, perhaps you should try writing a [pixel shader](https://www.raywenderlich.com/70208/opengl-es-pixel-shaders-tutorial).

- Set the viewport to the base image dimensions and draw a quad from (-1, 1).
- Your fragment shader will now operate on each pixel, known as a texel.  Get the texel with `gl_FragCoord`
- Sample the base and overlay by texel e.g. using `texelFetch`
- If the texel is outside of the overlay, set the overlay's rgba values to 0

For example

```
//fragment shader
uniform ivec2 overlayDim;
uniform sampler2D baseTexture;
uniform sampler2D overlayTexture;

void main() {
   vec2 texelf = floor(gl_FragCoord.xy);
   ivec2 texel = (int(texelf.x), int(texelf.y));

  vec4 base = texelFetch(baseTexture, texel, 0);
  vec4 overlay = texelFetch(overlayTexture, texel, 0);

  float overlayIsValid = float(texel.x < overlayDim.x && texel.y < overlayDim.y);

  overlay *= overlayIsValid;

  //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you sample outside the range of the texture is controlled by the value you set for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` using `glTexParameteri()`.

In full OpenGL, you could set the value to `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER`, set the border color to a value with alpha 0.0, and be done with it. But texture borders are not available in OpenGL ES 2.0 (the option is introduced in ES 3.2, but not in earlier versions).

Without this, I can think of two options:

- If you have control over the texture data, you could set a one pixel border to transparent values. The `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` then gives you a transparent value when sampling outside the range.
- Check the range in the fragment shader.

The fragment shader code for the second option could look something like this (untested):

```
mediump vec3 col = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).xyz;

if (all(greaterThan(textureCoordinate2, vec2(0.0))) &&
    all(lessThan(textureCoordinate2, vec2(1.0))))
{
    mediump vec3 overlay = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2).xyz;
    col = mix(col, overlay, overlay.a);
}

gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
```

Compared to your original code, also note the use of vector operations. Whenever there is a good way of operating on vectors, it will make the code simpler. It will also make the job of the optimizer easier for GPUs with vector operations.